# Python 2.7 'module' object has no attribute 'setPenRadius'

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I am trying to run Princeton University's [htree.py](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/23recursion/htree.py.html) which imports [stddraw.py](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stddraw.py.html). Although I have both files saved locally in the same file, I getting an error saying that 'module' object has no attribute 'setPenRadius' although it is clearly defined in the stddraw file. Any help on what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

```
stddraw v0.2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htree.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "htree.py", line 37, in main
    stddraw.setPenRadius(0.0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setPenRadius'
```

Comment: can you post your code here

Comment: To make it easier for others to test the demo code: I think you left an accidental trailing slash in the first link to htree.py

Comment: @JayParikh I haven't written any of my own code. I'm just using the files linked (stddraw is rather large) I just wanted to test stddraw with a program coded by the same people but it seems it can't find methods in the class.

Comment: Please give a full traceback of the exception you're getting. We don't know what you're doing when you get the exception (since you didn't tell us), and the traceback will show all the details.

Comment: @Blckknght not sure if thats the full traceback but it's all that appears in my interpreter

Comment: can you also share the source code of `toothpicks.py`?

Comment: @hansaplast I have tried running it in CodeRunner and executing it in terminal, both have the same issue.

Comment: @hansaplast I planned to play around with the code for another project once I got it running. I've changed the name back to htree.py to avoid confusion

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct stddraw.py that you linked to? Your sample output prints "stddraw v0.2", but this doesn't appear anywhere in your code. I googled for "stddraw v0.2" and found this http://www.cs.bc.edu/~muller/teaching/cs101/f13/dist/code/stddraw.py which unlike the file you linked to, doesn't have a setPenRadius() function

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a different module with the same name in your path that is being loaded instead of the `stddraw.py` that you linked to. Try redownloading the [stddraw.py](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stddraw.py) module that you want and rename it to something else, e.g. `stddrawprinceton.py`. To use the module with the new name, change the import statement in `htree.py` to:

`import stddrawprinceton as stddraw`